# Missing resource in BundleConfig.cs MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I was hoping someone can catch something that I missed. I am bundling my javascript files in BundleConfig.cs, which is in the folder `App_Data` like this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/customScript").Include(                   
                    "~/Views/Summary/storedata.js",                      
                    "~/Views/Summary/UploadData.js",
                    "~/Views/Summary/manipulateData.js"));
```

When I load the page it says that the resource can not be found. I double check and the path is correct. It seems that the resources in View can not be loaded. I have some scripts from a library in the Scripts folder that is able to load

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/frameworkScripts").Include(
                    ...
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.browser.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js",
                    ....
```

Is there something I am forgetting to check? Maybe help point me in the right direction?

**Update**

As requested I am loading the bundle here in my _Layout.cshtml which is in the shared folder and that folder is in the Views folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- Meta tag used for the finger gesture needed for swiping -->
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />   
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
  ....
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/frameworkScripts")
  ....
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customScript")
```

The error that I am getting is in the web console, this is just one of the error the other is the same error diff. resource

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://localhost:53228/Views/Summary/manipulateData.js
```

Comment: can you post the full error you are receiving? and the line in your .cshtml that loads your bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that in ASP.NET MVC you cannot access a `Views` directory via a URL. So that you'd have to go through a controller to get to a view. That's how routing works.

For this reason there is a `Scripts` directory (and `Content` directory for css, images, etc.). If there are many scripts per view, create a directory for each view under `Scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard ASP.Net MVC project, there are 2 Web.config files (one in the root, one in the Views Diectory).  In the second Web.config, you will find the following:

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*"
          type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

this stops the server from serving any files directly from the Views folder or subfolders.  You can replace it with the following code and still be safe:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="*.aspx" verb="*"
        type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    <add path="*.master" verb="*"
        type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    <add path="*.ascx" verb="*"
        type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```